# Image path doesnot working in YII framework?

Tags: html, image, yii

Here I have one sub domain and folder in following URL [buyjapon](http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/buyjapon/).This is website is belong Yii framework.

basically,we called image path as `<img src="/images/usd_C.jpg" />` .I create folder in my domain in migrate into that folder, then i want to call image src just like  that `<img src="/images/usd_C.jpg" />` but it will not show image properly.
I have include base href in head tag

```
 <head>
    <base href="http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/buyjapon">
  </head>
```

**Note:** When i call image src  like this `<img src="buyjapon/images/usd_C.jpg" />` it will shown correctly. but i want to change entire website by adding buyjapon in image src.

How to call this..Please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

If your URL's to pages do not require the /buyjapon folder name to be present, then one option would be to create an image controller, that opens up the requested image from the images folder, and outputs it to the data stream. I do this in situations where different translations of the same image are required for different users.

However, it looks like maybe your webserver is not set up correctly - if you are using apache have you set up a virtual host for your website? That will probably solve all your issues. Look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html and at your current virtualhost setup to see what to do.

Comment: Normally i get the result like as _" /home/demoosiz/public_html/buyjapon/protected/config/main.php "_ using this code : $config = dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
Can you please give another solution?

Comment: Yes, but if you move index.php up one level, your URL's should all be relative to it, not to the sub folder.

Comment: Yes @zack Newsham,  when i migrate into one level down, it will affect other my website. Index.php will overwrite existing one.Please give some idea for this...